# Why is Phantasm II available on Bluray while the other movies in this series are not?

Tags: distribution

As far as I can tell, Phantasm 1, 3, and 4 are only available on DVD. Is there a reason why this is so? I can't tell if the rights are owned by a different company, but I don't believe this to be the case.

And the second movie is hardly such a classic that it would be included in the Criterion Collection or anything like that.

So what gives?

Comment: For a **long** time, Phantasm II was the only one **not** on DVD.  In fact, I had to track down the laserdisc because that was the only way to own it.  This likely created a pseudo-false sense of demand for the studio when they did finally release it, which in turn prompted a Blu-Ray release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a while now Scream Factory (Shout Factory) has had distribution rights for Phantasm 2. Anchor Bay had the rights for 1,3, and 4 but the DVDs are out of print and AB didn't seem to do much with the movies beyond their initial DVD releases. Anchor Bay no longer holds the distribution rights; I have no idea who does. If Scream Factory ends up with the films that would be cause for celebration as they make an art out of re-releasing old horror films on Blu ray and making some fine collector sets...unfortunately all of my online searching hasn't turned up any info on who does hold the rights to the films. Fingers Crossed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll keep my fingers crossed with you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your wishes have finally been granted by a company called Well Go USA.  I didn't read this entire thread so I'm not positive what held up the Blu-Ray release, but at least now you can see that one is on the way.  At this point, it seems Coscarelli is doing a George Lucas impersonation and putzing with some CGI editing.

http://forum.blu-ray.com/showthread.php?t=271146